# Why firefox shows some connections are not secure?

Tags: certificate-authority, firefox

I am using internet by connecting  mobile phone to my laptop using usb. From yesterday,my browser (firefox) shows [image: like this] for all most all website. Why this happen? How can i solve this?

Comment: If you want to know the _technical details_ which make the certificate untrusted, then opening the _technical details_ section might be a smart move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date/time on your device maybe invalid.

All SSL certificates have a start and end period.  Certificates can be compromised and its a good practice to renew them.

Comment: It's true this is a possible cause, but it would be more useful to the asker if you could give a brief explanation as to why.

Comment: @Iszi  good point,  updated

Answer (score 3):

Your mobile provider might be routing everything thru a proxy server that is doing SSL inspection, so it can do content filtering or bandwidth optimisation, which Firefox is detecting as a man-in-the-middle attack.