# What are the steps to take after adding an invalid certificat authority?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

in order to pay my bills online internet , I have to go through the website for my internet provider , type the login and password then I redirect to a page **your connection is not private** i proceed to the website then i give the number of credit card and the password to pay my bills. Today i get some useful informations from [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80662/i-cant-access-websites-that-use-https-instead-getting-the-message-your-connec) Maybe i am doing something wrong , What are the steps to take after adding an invalid certificat authority?

in the future, how can I proceed to the payment of my bills safely and without using a VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ....  your connection is not private i proceed to the website ...
>   What are the steps to take after adding an invalid certificat authority?

You probably did not add a new certificate authority. If you simply clicked to make an exception in order to proceed you've only added an exception for this specific certificate used on this specific site. This is different from adding a new certificate authority (CA) which would be able to issue certificates for lots of sites. Steps to adding a new CA are more complex then just agreeing to add an exception.

The steps to remove an exception you have added to a browser depend on the browser. Google will help when you ask [the right question](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+ssl+exception+browser).

> in the future, how can I proceed to the payment of my bills safely and without using a VPN?

If you get a security warning only for a single specific web site then chances are high that this is caused by a bad certificate on the site itself. Contact the site owners in this case so that they fix it.

But if you get such a warning for most sites then either the time on your computer is way off and thus most certificates are considered not yet valid or already expired. Or there is some SSL interception going on (i.e. man in the middle). This might be legal if you are inside a company and you should contact your local administrator on how to proceed. If you are in some public network then it might be caused by a hacker playing with the customers and you should not proceed. If this happens inside your own network something is very wrong there which you should fix before continuing with sensitive transactions.

Comment: @GAD3R: Google is a search engine not a browser. Did you mean Google Chrome? Did you try to search on how to remove an exception using the search link in my answer?

Comment: chromium web browser

Comment: @GAD3R: easy to find with google:  http://superuser.com/questions/970383/how-do-i-remove-security-certificate-exceptions-from-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to weaponize your browser, I do recommend you to use Firefox. Second - an add-ons :

- Perspectives project [add-on link](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/perspectives/)
- Certificate Patrol [add-on link](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/)
- Calomel SSL Validation [add-on link](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/calomel-ssl-validation/)
- Web of Trust [add-on link](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/wot-safe-browsing-tool/)

This will do you good to arm your web browser via flagging the insecure/weakly secure connections and showing you **exactly** which certificates + CA's are in use and about to be added. You will be able **not to add** a certificate you don;t trust. To pay to any firm you can use a bank transfer, for your information : ask your ISP how to pay them by bank transfer and try to do this. Feel free to ask further questions - one of my areas of interest is a personal privacy and security in Internet, so I'd like to help you!

Comment: You don't seem to answer the question. The main question seems to be what to do now that the OP has possibly added a bad cert. You don't touch that. Then you state that the OP should add a bunch of add-ons, but don't state how they will help or what the OP should do afterward. And I'm not sure what you mean by "weaponize"

Comment: @NeilSmithline CertificatePatrol will show him *exact* certificates, including the injected CA one(s) - and he will be able to delete/disable them in the Firefox settings. "Weaponize" = provide a right weapons against threats and proper armor for the attacks deflection. Should I add some step-by-step guide to show how *exactly* a CA certificate must be dealt with?